# wcf project design

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I'm working on a WCF project and wanted to get some ideas on how to design the classes, if i'm doing it the right way.  Currently I have 2 interfaces IUser and ICase, in 2 separate class files (IUser.cs and ICase.cs), I'd like to keep them separate for readability.  When implementing them I'm building a partial class which implements them, so I then have 2 other files User.cs and Case.cs, which have the implementation as:

```
public partial class AppService : ICase

public partial class AppService : IUser
```

This way again the implementation is kept separate.  When building the web.config file's endpoints, I have 2 separate endpoints for each contract.

```
<endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="AppService.ICase" />
<endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="AppService.IUser" />
```

My question was this is typically how it's done?  Or is there a way to combine it so there is only 1 endpoint, rather then 2?  I'd like to keep them in separate interfaces, but if I add more interfaces later do I need to keep adding more endpoints to expose that functionality, or is there a way to have multiple interfaces but only one endpoint that exposes them all?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only contstraint regarding contracts in WCF is that you should have one explicit contract. But you are free to combine multiple interfaces into one:

```
public interface ICombinedInterface : ICase, IUser
```

and use the combined interface as your service contract.

The question: "whether should there be one or more endpoints?" doesn't have an easy answer. It depends on what your requirements and priorities are. From the client's point of view, it should not matter much.